# Google Cloud Speech to Text no output

Tags: laravel, google-cloud-platform, console, command, google-cloud-speech

Can't figure out why there is no output from this request. I loaded a 44100hz mp3 into this. It just outputs an empty object through dd(). I don't think its anything to do with the credentials. As iv enabled the API from the Google Cloud Console.

```
            $speech = new SpeechClient([
                'credentials' => storage_path("app/compute/google/cloud/service_accounts/keys/key1.json"),
            ]);



            $file = file_get_contents($options["input_url"]);


           // change these variables if necessary
            $encoding = AudioEncoding::LINEAR16;
            $sampleRateHertz = 44100;
            $languageCode = 'en-US';
            // get contents of a file into a string

            // set string as audio content
            $audio = (new RecognitionAudio())
                ->setContent($file);

            // set config
            $config = (new RecognitionConfig())
                ->setEncoding($encoding)
                ->setSampleRateHertz($sampleRateHertz)
                ->setLanguageCode($languageCode);

            $response = $speech->recognize($config, $audio);

            dd(($response->serializeToJsonString()));

            foreach ($response->getResults() as $result) {
                    $alternatives = $result->getAlternatives();
                    $mostLikely = $alternatives[0];
                    $transcript = $mostLikely->getTranscript();
                    $confidence = $mostLikely->getConfidence();
                    $this->info('Transcript: %s' . PHP_EOL, $transcript);
                    $this->info('Confidence: %s' . PHP_EOL, $confidence);
            }


    }
```

Comment: Take a look at [debugging small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for some inspiration. If you are already familiar with debugging theory you can skip it but if not, it's a good primer. I'd probably start with throwing in some logger.log calls in your functions to ensure that they are getting called as you expect. You can also step through it but I tend to start with logging... just personal preference. If you are getting calls to all the functions as expected then step through and look at the objects as then come into and leave existence.

Comment: The issue should be apparent at some point ... the fix may not be, but the issue should be. Good luck! If you get a bit more info as to where the problem is and don't know how to proceed, edit your question. If you sort it out, answer your own question. :)

Comment: I took a look at some, troubleshooting information last night, it said that, this behavior is expected. But that's not very useful